# Problems with Flask Ipython jinja2 integration

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask, ipython, jinja2, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a flask app with Bootstrap styling that would include a ipython notebook (static converted to HTML with nbconvert) I attempted to add the HTML code from the notebook inside a jinja2 `{% block %}` in order to use `render_template` to extend my app template.

The problem is that the HTML code of the notebook has several `}}` that are interpreted as jinja2 with the `render_template` causing rendering errors (expected comment end). Has anyone tried a similar setup or has any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the ipython's html inside a `{% raw %} {% endraw %}` block as in the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#escaping)

If the notebooks are being generated automatically through some script, you can probably modify the script a little bit to put `{% raw %}` at the beginning of the file and `{% endraw %}` at the end of the file after its generated by nbconvert. something like this:

```
ipython nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb
sed -i -e '1i{% raw %}\' notebook.html
echo '{% endraw %}' >> notebook.html
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Moinul. That works just fine (still have some problems with the Notebook CSS overriding some of the original bootstrap CSS but will look into it in more detail to find the instance).